# How to popup window of a certain size based on a certain position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popupwindow

Assuming I have a page with an iframe positioned somewhere on a page that is 400px by 400px. Is it possible to click a button that causes the contents of the iframe to pop out in a new window such that it remains the same size of the iframe and is positioned right over the area where the iframe is on its original page?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: No, it’s not. I have set my browser to open full tabs only, and disregard any popup window measurements a site author might specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this:-

```
<a href="/abc.php" 
 onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,
location=no,status=no,‌​menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,
 width='400px',height='400px')" />
```